# combine AQGridView with HJCache

Tags: aqgridview, hjcache

I am trying to combine AQGridView with HJCache.

However, separately, both works fine. but i combine them together, it seems that they 're not compatible with each other.

Any one done this before? Can i have a hint?

Comment: Or, how can I make AQGridView load images from internet asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which has an ImageView Category that let's you load images asynchronously.

```
[content.imageView setImageWithURL:thumbURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbnail_loading.jpg"]];
```

content is a view with an ImageView named 'imageview' as a subview.